# SQL Server 2000 DTS Package Failing with "The number of failing rows exceeds the maximum specified"

Tags: sql-server, dts

I have inherited a SQL Server 2000 DTS package that migrates data from SQL Server to Oracle. This package moves about 20 tables' data to Oracle every night with no transformations, and it is then transformed by a set of SPs and used by a GIS application.

Twice this week, during the migration between SQL Server and Oracle, the package has failed with "The number of failing rows exceeds the maximum specified". It has failed on a different table each time, though.

Each time it's failed, we've rerun the process the next morning and it has worked. Because the process works the second time it's run, it makes me think the data is being changed by someone or something between the initial failure and our successful second run.

I would like to change the DTS package to log the failing rows in a text document so we can compare them later.

Can someone help me with that? I can't seem to figure that part out.

Scott

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. I found the Exceptions File under the Options tab.

Comment: Which is where you would go to change the number of row failures allowed, as well as to set up a log.